how to segment for a subcategory of the data and not the others when they are in the same object
please I need help with this. I have a table with tasks and their status, completed tasks have an end date.
I need a page to have a segmenter that takes the closing date (or some calculated form) and this filters the ones completed by this date but
leaves the others that do not have a date alone. Is not with the interactions because the data is in the same object (table or graph):
Example in the picture, initial table with status, a semgment,a table with what exclude etc, results.
Now if I put that, when I move the date filter from the minimum date it excludes those that do not have a date.
I already tried to generate a column that brings me the maximum closing date to put it to those that do not have it and so
I am always using this column as a segmenter, but this maximum remains static and not dynamic
ff = VARMaxAllDate = CALCULATE(Max('POA 2024'[Close Date]), ALL('POA 2024')) VAR HasClosingDate = NOT(ISBLANK('POA 2024'[Close Date])) RETURN IF(HasClosingDate, 'POA 2024'[Close Date], MaxAllDate)   

or
ff = VARMaxAllDate = CALCULATE(Max('POA 2024'[Close Date]), ALLselected('POA 2024'[Close Date])) VAR HasClosingDate = NOT(ISBLANK('POA 2024'[Close Date])) RETURN IF(HasClosingDate, 'POA 2024'[Close Date], MaxAllDate)


link to chart-table

To filter your table visual by Close Date but keep the rows with blank values try this:

Create a Date Table
User Date Table with slicer
Create the following measure
Add Measure to your table visual's filters as Show items when value is 1

Date Table:
_Date Table = CALENDAR(MIN('POA 2024'[Close Date]), MAX('POA 2024'[Close Date]))

Note: Do not create relationship between _Date Table and POA 2024
Use the _Date Table[Date] column in your slicer.
Measure:
ShowRows = 
var slicerVals = ALLSELECTED('_Date Table'[Date]) //Get all selected values from slicer.

var showRow = IF(
                ISEMPTY(
                    FILTER(slicerVals,
                        VAR closedDate = MAXX('POA 2024', 'POA 2024'[Close Date]) //Retrieves Close Date from Table and stores it into a variable to reuse.
                        RETURN
                        closedDate IN slicerVals //Checks if Closed Date is in Slicer Selection
                        || closedDate = BLANK()  //Checks if Closed Date is blank, because we want to show these rows
                    )
                     )
                     ,0,1) //Returns 0 if the the criteria is not met, or 1 if the criteria is met. 1 = Show, 0 = Hide

return showRow


Edit: Adding filtering for visual below:
The measure requires all fields in the visual to work properly.
So select the visual and put your Closed Date column under the main group.


Hi, I did this exercise, however it has a problem. When using a date range it excludes those that do not have a closing date, that is, all those that are not finalized. Thank you very much for your collaboration and I remain attentive to your comments.

@ccdiazni A date table is needed for your slicer to prevent filtering of blanks. I updated my answer to address this.

hi, update and it works for the table, but i am making a graph (ring) that counts the number of tasks by status and it doesn't work because it removes the finished ones. This graph should show the same as the table but grouped by status. like I said , it discards the finished ones. In the post I leave the  link to image, out of 11 results of the table there are 5, not more, all the finished ones are eliminated.  EDIT, if  the date filter is before the global maximum of the table, it doesn't filter anything, if it is after, it excludes the finalized ones. thanks for your help.

@ccdiazni that visual was not a part of the original question. However, I edited my answer to include steps to help you get that working. If this helps, please mark this answer as accepted. Thank you.

Hi nick, thanks for all your help. I did not know that put the closed date in the chart  would make it act as a table and set the context of the maxx
